# Using 'reduce' vs 'for' loop for returning boolean

Tags: functional-programming, loops

I was wondering what people think about using a reduce function vs loop `for` returning true if a condition exists.

Example:

```
var a = [1, 5, 7, 4, 2, 5, 3];

var greaterThan5 = a.reduce(function(prev, val) {
    return (prev || val > 5);
}, false);

vs

var greaterThan5 = false;
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] > 5) {
        greaterThan5 = true;
        break;
    }
}

vs

var i = 0;
var greaterThan5 = false;
while(!greaterThan5 && i < a.length) {
    greaterThan5 = (a[i] > 5);
    i++;
}
```

The `for` loop and `while` loop will exit when the condition is true, but I think the reduce syntax is easier to read and gives less room for run-time errors.

Comment: In terms of functional programming, most functional languages don't have for or while loops. Indeed they don't have any control structure syntax. Only functions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, why not use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which seems to perfectly match what you're actually trying to do.

> The some() method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

Of course, that doesn't really answer your question: whether to use the for loop, or the call to `Array.protoype.reduce()`? Let me also try to answer that. The question is mostly regarding weighing performance against clarity of code.

For performance: measure, not just using random arrays, but using arrays that make sense in your project. No need in selecting a method that works fast on 1,000,000 element arrays, when all you need to process are arrays of up to 10 elements.

More importantly, only worry about performance when performance is an issue.

With respect to clarity. I actually think the explicit for-loop is more clear than the `Array.prototype.reduce()`. But, what matters most is, what the people on your team will find the most clear. If one of your team finds an explicit for-loop more clear, it's probably better to use that, if only because it uses a less advanced set of features.

Comment: `.reduce()` offers an opportunity to expose colleagues to the greater set of tools - its also standard since 2011 or there about(s) so short of something like a necessity for that sort of legacy support - it could be novel given the argument spec. `some()` also accomplishes the novelty with the same service agreement, of course. love it.

Comment: I personally find `reduce()` unclear in this example because, as you point out, `reduce()` is not what the OP actually wants to do. `some()` definitely beats all of the above.

Comment: _what the people on your time will find the most clear_ a bit hard to understand. Is time a typo for team?

Comment: Also be aware of [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for the *and* version of the short-circuiting reduce.

Comment: @Caridorc: yes, it was a typo. Darkhogg corrected it now.

Answer (score 5):

For most functional languages, neither.

There is usually a reducing function which short circuts as you want it to.

In F# this is List.exists so you example would be

```
List.exists (fun x -> x > 5) a
```

In Haskell (with partial application of > to make a point free solution)

```
any (> 5) a
```

Comment: The above example could be written even shorter with the pointfree style as `List.exists ((>)5) a`

Comment: thank you. I found that javascript has the [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function that does the same thing.

Comment: @OverlyExcessive i dont think that will do what you think it will, that will bind the first argument of > to 5 i.e. you will be checking 5 > x

Comment: @jk Right, but if you reverse the comparison it will give the same results as the lambda.

Comment: @OverlyExcessive yes i take your point - added point free haskell version - as f# doesnt appeat to have away to do this without changing the operator i'd argue that it hurts readability there